# Too many grammars in Microsoft Speech SDK 11

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar, microsoft-speech-platform

I write simple speech recognition app wich can load grammars into engine.

But i see, that can not load many grammars into engine not more then 1024 grammars.

```
Additional information: Too many grammars have been loaded. Number of grammars cannot exceed 1024.
```

And when i load 1024 grammars- it does not recognize input stream `.wav` (and my speech) file:

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");

        // Create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine instance.
         _sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU"));

         _sre.SpeechHypothesized += _sre_SpeechHypothesized;
         _sre.SpeechDetected += _sre_SpeechDetected;
         _sre.SetInputToWaveFile(@"c:\Test\Wavs\Wavs-converted\file.wav");


 public void LoadGrammarIntoEngine(IEnumerable<String> textColl)
    {
        Choices choises = new Choices();
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");


        if (choises != null && textColl != null)
        {
            choises.Add(textColl.ToArray());

            if (gb != null)
                gb.Append(choises);
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            if (_sre.Grammars.Count < 1024)
            {
                Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
                if (_sre != null && g != null)
                    _sre.LoadGrammar(g);
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("too many grammars");
            }
        }

    }
```

P.S. when i load 5-10 grammars (100 words each)- it works well.

Maybe i can\should use more than one recognition engine together?

Comment: Why on earth do you need so many grammars?   You should be able to merge them using [`GrammarBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Choices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.choices(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, but if my Grammar is very big- 1000+ words (i use word list,not SGRS-grammar)- Speech Recognizer can not recognize words.

Comment: If you're building a set of *phrases*, you should be able to have over 1000 words with no problem.   If you're trying to recognize a set of 1000 words that can occur in any order, you're effectively trying to build a dictation engine out of a command & control engine, and in my experience, that never works.   To get good free text recognition, you need an engine that's capable of understanding a language model, rather than just an acoustic model.

Comment: Eric Brown, yes i try to recognize speech to text with words in any order. do you know some good engine for that?
I set a 5000 words\phrases -and it works hard.

Comment: @EricBrown,yes  try to recognize speech to text with words in any order. do you know some good engine for that? I set a 5000 words\phrases -and it works hard.
If i will create srgs-grammar-can it help me to recognize more than 2000+ words?
Now i use just a list of words in text file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with other engines, particularly for Russian SR.   As I said earlier, if you're trying to make a dictation engine out of a command & control engine, you're going to have trouble.   If you have a set of phrases (arranged in a tree structure), you can easily have tens of thousands of *sentences* - that is to say, the combinatorial expansion of the grammar would have tens of thousands of phrases.   However, typically, you end up with under a thousand *words* to generate these phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, you're fundamentally taking the wrong approach.   You need to be using something like [System.Speech.Recognition.DictationGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar(v=vs.110).aspx) - which uses the Microsoft desktop SR engine.

This will accept most English words.   If you need to limit it to 1000 words, there are a couple of options.

If your word list contains words that aren't in the default word list (which is quite extensive), you can use the [Lexicon Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717919(v=vs.85).aspx), which, sadly, aren't exposed through System.Speech.Recognition, so you'll have to drop to SAPI to use them.

This also assumes that you can reject out-of-vocabulary recognitions.   If that's not the case, 
you can use the [Dictation Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23262), which will let you build a custom language model; be warned that it's built by speech scientists for speech scientists, so the documentation is pretty hard going.

In practice, users will say out-of-vocabulary things; it's best to check for them and reject them.  Small (and yes, 1000 words is small) vocabularies tend to have problems with false positives (user says something out-of-vocabulary that gets recognized as something in-vocabulary).   This happens with command-and-control grammars, as well.

Comment: Unfortunally, i need Russian language and Microsoft Speech (desktop)-have not it. And it will be very good if i havent limit of words. I say that i can recognize so-so - 5000 words, but i need more:)

Comment: Time to look for another SR API, then, unfortunately.